# Programa para hacer sucesión de Fibonacci no da resultado esperado

Tags: c++

Resulta que el programa que he elaborado para hacer la [sucesión de Fibonacci](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sucesi%C3%B3n_de_Fibonacci) n veces -valor ingresado por el usuario- me da el siguiente resultado erróneo:

> (139)bash: line 1:    22 Done                    printf '12' 23
>   Segmentation fault      (core dumped) | ./program

Adjunto el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int fibonacci(int n, int i);
int main(){
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout << fibonacci(n, i);
  }
}

int fibonacci(int n, int i){
  if (n == 0){
   return 0; 
  }
  else if (n == 1){
   return 1; 
  }
  else{
   return fibonacci(n, i - 1) + fibonacci(n, i - 2);  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El programa te da excepción porque entra en bucle infinito y al no disminuir `n` el programa se queda sin memoria ya que siempre entrará en el último `else` y no saldrá nunca.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando el Comentario de [Chariot](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/50452/chariot) te muestro la implementacion de las correcciones que antes te mencionaron:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int fibonacci(int n);

int main(){
int n;
cin >> n;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    cout << fibonacci(i) << ' ';
 }
}

int fibonacci(int n){
  if (n == 0){
   return 0; 
  }
  else if (n == 1){
   return 1; 
  }
  else{
   return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);  
  }
}
```

Saludos, espero te sirvan.

Comment: Un truquito para hacerlo mas eficiente es crear un diccionario para almacenar las secuencias ya calculadas y no tener que volver a hacer el calculo!